# how do you format this date type in javascript

Tags: jquery, date, format

how do you format a date into the format **30-Apr-10** in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few libraries out there for this, you can use something like [Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) ([under 4kb completely uncompressed](http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js)), then your usage would be like this:

```
var currentDateString = new Date().format("dd-mmm-yy");
```

Though, if possible, I'd stick to 4-digit years :)

Comment: If using ASP.NET AJAX a format function is available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/bb310850.aspx